# A Column Has Its Foreign Key In various Tables

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, multiple-columns

I have following tables in SQL Server 2008:

```
Academic, Experience, Seeker, Employee, Job, Company, City
```

All of these tables have a `LocationId` column that is the used foreign key and it references to `CityId` and `cityId` is a column of the `City` table.

How can I retrieve the city name for each of the table by referencing `cityid`?

Say I want to know simultaneously that, city of seeker, city where he got his academic degrees, city of organization from where he got experience, city of job of which the vacancy is announced.

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this:

```
SELECT Academic.FieldName, City.CityName
FROM Academic
JOIN City ON City.CityID = Academic.LocationID
```

I hope this helps.

UPDATE

Based on the idea that we can connect Academic.AcademicID with Seeker.SeekerID in order to follow the same person, here is another approach:

```
SELECT a.FieldName, 
ac.CityName AS AcademicCity,
sc.CityName AS SeekerCity
FROM Academic a
INNER JOIN City ac 
ON ac.CityID = a.LocationID
LEFT JOIN Seeker s
ON s.SeekerID = a.AcademicID
LEFT JOIN City sc 
ON sc.CityID = s.LocationID
```

Here I am showing both inner joins and left joins.  (You should avoid the old-fashioned "comma" syntax for inner joins, like "FROM table1, table2", since this is sometimes ambiguous or incorrect.)

The inner join assumes that we can find matching records in the Academic table and the City table;  if there is no match, then no records are returned.

But I want to return the Academic City even if there is no match in the Seeker table.  That's why I used a left join there, and for the Seeker City as well.  If there is no match, the original record is still returned, but the Seeker City will come back NULL.

So a left join allows NULLs in the table that is being left joined.  Notice we still have to start with a record in the Academic table.  You should choose the table that you want to start with carefully.  It doesn't have to be the Academic table.  You could start with the Seeker table and left join to the Academic table:

```
FROM Seeker s
LEFT JOIN Academic a
ON a.AcademicID = s.SeekerID
```

This will return different results depending on the records in each table.  You have to be careful when you decide which table to start with, and when to use inner joins and left joins.  It depends on what you are trying to do, and you have to understand clearly exactly what question you want to ask the database.

There is also a separate problem with these tables.  It is generally considered poor database design to have a table structure where Academic.AcademicID matches Seeker.SeekerID.  Each table should have its own primary key (PK), which doesn't depend on any other table.  A table can also have foreign keys (FK) that point to the PKs of other tables.  So the properly **normalized** structure here would start with a Person table with a PersonID PK.  The Academic table would have its own AcademicID PK, but it would also have a PersonID FK that points back to the Person table.  And so on.

By the way, it's perfectly good normalized database design for many tables to have FKs pointing to a single table.  So it's not a problem that many tables (Academic, Seeker, etc) all point to City.CityID.  Usually you will see the FK named the same as the PK, e.g., Academic.CityID instead of Academic.LocationID, but calling it LocationID is okay too.

Comment: bro i am able to do this, but at the same moment if i also want to know the city name of the seeker in this same query, then how can i do this? i mean retrieving cityName of seeker and cityName of the organization from where he got his academic degree,, while both academic and seeker possess locationId that refers to same Cityid column in the city table.

Comment: @RanjhaniSaddam What tells you that an entry in the Academic table and an entry in the Seeker table refer to the same person?  Is there something like a Person table with a Person.PersonID primary key, and the other tables have foreign keys like Academic.PersonID and Seeker.PersonID?  We know how to get to the City table, but that doesn't tell us how Academic and Seeker are related.

Comment: Select S.CityName As SeekerCity, A.CityName As AcademicCity
    From Seeker INNER JOIN City S
    On dbo.Seeker.LocationId = S.CityId,
    Academic INNER JOIN City A
On dbo.Academic.LocationId = A.CityId
Where Seeker.SeekerId = 1
And Academic.AcademicId = 1